# numpy way to encode a range of values into n discrete levels

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I have an array of floats ranging from 0 to 100:

```
[1.2, 3.0, 25.0, 80.9]
```

What is a `numpy`-idiomatic way of encoding them into quantiles (or by extension, any `n`-tile).

In effect, I should have:

```
[0, 0, 1, 4]
```

Comment: Floor division, i.e. `A // (100/5)` might be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple way:

```
(a / 20).astype(int)
```

Or for more compact storage:

```
(a / 20).astype('i1')
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized that this process is called "binning" as in putting elements into bins. It looks like [`numpy.digitize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html) does the job well.

Comment: My answer is 3-4x faster.